# Angularjs - Hide Element if element doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

i'm working on ACTIVITI and need to hide this button:

[image: Button]

if no process are instantiate, i.e. if server return this (show button):

[image: noprocess]

instead of this (in this case button hide):

[image: yesprocess]

This is the code for button i used in HTML:

```
<div ng-controller=getDeploy>


            <h3>Deployments Info</h3>
            <br>
            <table class="table" table-bordered table-hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Deployment</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Url</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="info" ng-repeat="x in names">
                        <td class="danger">{{ x.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                        <td class="warning">{{ x.deploymentTime }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.category }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.url }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left;" ng-controller="InstanziateProcess">
            <button ng-click="processdef()">
                Instanzia il Processo
            </button>
        </div>
```

and for JS:

```
function InstanziateProcess($scope, $http, Base64) {

$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('kermit' + ':' + 'kermit');
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions")
    .then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
        var key = response.data.data[0].key;


        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances",
            data: {
                processDefinitionKey: key
            },
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('kermit' + ':' + 'kermit'),
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        $scope.processdef = function () {
            $http(req).then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        };
    });};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

```
<button ng-hide="bValue" ng-click="processdef()">
            Instanzia il Processo
</button>
```

code in controller

```
$scope.bValue = false;
$scope.processdef = function () {
        $http(req).then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.bValue = false;

            if(response.data && response.data.data.length) // may change depends on response data
                $scope.bValue = true;
        });
    };
```

Comment: It could be response.data.length not response.data.data.length . Depends on what response contains.

Comment: I solved, i used data.total !=0 and it works :) Thanks you anyway for Idea :D

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it

```
<button ng-click="processdef()" ng-show="YOUR_CONDITION_WHICH_CAN_BE_CONTROLLER_FUNCTION_RETURN_VALUE">

    Instanzia il Processo
</button>
```

NB: You should use controller as syntax in Angular :)
NNB: You might want to use ng-if instead of ng-show - ng-if prevents the element being included in the HTML, ng-show includes the element in the HTML but just makes the element hidden via the automatic adding of an hidden class / attribute

your function should return true or false.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, the button should be shown when no results were received?

```
<button ng-if="names.total==0" ng-click="processdef()">
```

However, the example JSON, the JS code and the HTML don't fit together at all.  Where do you assign to `$scope.names`, the variable you use for the `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Here:

`function getDeploy($scope, $http, Base64) {

    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('kermit' + ':' + 'kermit');

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/deployments")
        .then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.names = response.data.data;
        });
};
`

Comment: Then it would be `ng-if="names.length==0"`

Answer (score 1):

`ng-hide` or `ng-show` will probably do what you need. In your angular controller that has that button within its scope, create a boolean variable, say, `processesAreRunning`. Then, in your HTML, add the `ng-show` directive:

```
<button ng-click="processdef()" ng-show="myController.processesAreRunning">
    Instanzia il Processo
</button>
```

Which says "display this button if `processesAreRunning` is `true`". Obviously replacing `myController` with the declared name of your controller.

With that logic in place, it's as simple as setting that variable after your HTTP request is finished based on what the server returns back to you.

---

If you're curious, here's more documentation on how exactly the `ng-show` directive works: [AngularJS: ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).